# Should I be suspicious of my HD enclosure?

Tags: hard-drive, enclosures

I used my older laptop for a little more than three years. When I replaced it with a newer one about a year ago, I removed the old hard drive and dropped it into a 2.5" enclosure. The drive is starting to click once when connecting it to a USB port, and I'm afraid it'll soon shuffle off the mortal coil.

But is it rational for me to suspect the enclosure of killing off the hard drive, or was it just the hard drive's expected time to die? I'd like to continue using the enclosure, but not if there's a larger-than-remote chance of it killing another drive.

Comment: Is the drive powered from the USB or does it have its own external power supply?

Comment: It's solely USB-powered; no additional power supply.

Comment: Does it come with, and are you using, a USB Y cable to use power from 2 USB ports?

Comment: It has a Y-cable, but it has always worked with just the main connector plugged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you insert the other (newer) 2.5" drive into the enclosure and see if it makes the same noise?

If **yes**, this is maybe just the controller of the enclosure itself spinning the disk up differently. I also had an external enclosure controller die on me recently and it all began with weird noises. The disk however ran fine in other PCs even after the enclosure died. This however doesn't mean your enclosure is faulty. Could be some power issues.

If **no**, run some tests on your drive (SMART, other tools) and see if your old drive makes the same noise in your laptop when you put it back in. Then you will likely have a hard disk problem and the enclosure should be fine.

Comment: If I use the newer drive in the enclosure, it leaves my only usable machine drive-less.

Comment: @taserian I mean just *testing* it ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not likely to be the enclosure. Have you run any tests on the drive to see if there are issues?  Most HD makers have a tool for this beyond SMART.